# How to not use application.html.erb file for a particular page in application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, partial-views

I want a particular page in the application to have different layout, while all others will have pretty much the same layout. However, the application.html.erb file is rendered for all the pages in application. How do I not use the application.html.erb file for a particular page?

Rails version : 3.2.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make another layout and specify and in your action you can simply use that as follow

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_affiliate_user!

  def daily_breakdown
    render :layout => 'admin_layout'
  end
end
```

to you different layout in all of the action you can do as follow

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'reporting_affiliate'
  before_filter :authenticate_affiliate_user!

  # your code here 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can use layout option or specify particular layout in action

```
Class SomeControlle < ...
  layout :admin_layout,:only=>[:some_action]
  def some_action
    #or
   render :layout=>'admin_layout'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `render :layout => 'special_layout'` in your controller where you render.